# Numpy logical and between two array with filter

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, logical-operators

```
x = [1,1,1,1]
y = [1,1,1,1]
np.logical_and(x == 1, y == 1)
```

Output: False

I am expecting an output of `[True, True, True, True]`. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `x` and `y` are **lists** not arrays. When you compare a list with an integer using `==` you'll always get `False`:

```
>>> [1,1,1,1] == 1
False
>>> [1,1,1,1] == 1
False
>>> np.logical_and(False, False)
False
```

You have to convert them to arrays, because arrays implement `==` to work element-wise:

```
>>> x = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1])
>>> x == 1
array([ True,  True,  True,  True])

>>> x = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1])
>>> y = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1])
>>> np.logical_and(x == 1, y == 1)
array([ True,  True,  True,  True])
```